# How to ignore wildcard folder structures with gitignore

Tags: wordpress, git, wildcard, gitignore

Example folder structure where `/` is `wp-content/`

```
/
/plugins
/plugins/akismet
/plugins/gravityforms
/plugins/woocommerce
/plugins/woocommerce-call-for-price
/plugins/woocommerce-dropdown-cart
```

etc etc...

How can I, using gitignore, ignore all the woocommerce related folders, without doing them all manually?

I was thinking something like `/plugins/woocommerce-**` but I honestly have no idea.

This is my current gitignore file

```
# Start default WordPress gitignore 
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/WordPress.gitignore
*.log
wp-config.php
wp-content/advanced-cache.php
wp-content/backup-db/
wp-content/backups/
wp-content/blogs.dir/
wp-content/cache/
wp-content/upgrade/
wp-content/uploads/
wp-content/wp-cache-config.php
wp-content/plugins/hello.php

/.htaccess
/license.txt
/readme.html
/sitemap.xml
/sitemap.xml.gz

# Ignore root files/folders as they are only changed with WP updates which we don't care to track
wp-admin/
wp-includes/
index.php
wp-activate.php
wp-blog-header.php
wp-comments-post.php
wp-config.php
wp-cron.php
wp-links-opml.php
wp-load.php
wp-login.php
wp-mail.php
wp-settings.php
wp-signup.php
wp-trackback.php
xmlrpc.php
README.md

# Ignore everything in wp-content apart from themes as this is essentially the WD
/wp-content/*
!/wp-content/themes
!/wp-content/themes/*

# Allow certain plugins through gitignore
!/wp-content/plugins/*
/wp-content/plugins/*
!/wp-content/plugins/woocoomerce
```

Comment: What about `/plugins/woocommerce-*`?

Comment: This doesn't have an affect unfortunately